# EasyNetQ - Delayed messages with topics

Tags: rabbitmq, easynetq

Is there a way of publishing delayed messages with topics with EasyNetQ? I was able to send direct delayed messages using the `FuturePublish` method, but it doesn't allow me to specify a topic.

Links:

[Scheduling Events with Future Publish](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Scheduling-Events-with-Future-Publish)

[RabbitMQ gets support for delayed messages delivery](http://www.mariuszwojcik.com/2015/04/28/rabbitmq-gets-support-for-delayed-messages-delivery/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible, yes. The delayed message exchange allows you to specify the type of exchange to use after the delay: fanout, topic, direct.

Looking at the code samples in the second link you posted, you should only need to change the "direct" configuration to "topic".

```
IDictionary args = new Dictionary
{
    {"x-delayed-type", "topic"} //----------- here
};
channel.ExchangeDeclare("DelayedTest", "x-delayed-message", true, false, args);
```

then follow the rest of the example as shown and you can publish with a topic for the routing key.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using the Advanced API, but it seems that it is the only way. I wonder why they haven't added topic as a parameter, similar to the regular Publish